# Contradictory Behaviour of Lambda Functions

Tags: haskell, lambda, evaluation

Using the following definitions:

```
lenDigits n = length (show n)
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

I evaluate the following

```
Prelude> ((lenDigits . factorial) 199) <= 199
False
Prelude> (\i -> ((lenDigits . factorial) i) <= i) 199
True
```

What is the reason for such behaviour? As I see it, the first expression is just the same as the second expression with the lambdas reduced.

Comment: You might also like comparing these two, which gets to the essence of the question, and avoids all the vagaries of having typeclasses lying around to confuse things: `(id True, id 'a')` is fine but `(\f -> (f True, f 'a')) id` is an error.

Comment: @DanielWagner Why does this happen? Isn't `id` polymorphic?

Comment: Yes indeed, `id` is polymorphic; and `\f -> ...` can be polymorphic; but inside the `...`, `f` itself is *not* polymorphic! `\f -> (f True, f 'a')` is already a type error without ever mentioning `id`. This restriction is put in place to make type inference easier and to preserve the desirable property that any term that can be given a type at all has a most general type.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because in the first expression the first `199` has type `Integer` and the second has `Int`. But in the second expression both have type `Int` and `factorial 199` can't be represented by the type `Int`.

Comment: Does this relate to monomorphism restriction?

Comment: I don't think so. In the first example, the first 199 is free to default to `Integer`, but the second one is forced to be treated as `Int` because it is being compared to the return value of `lenDigits`. In the second, `i` is forced to be `Int` for the same reason, which in turn forces 199 to be an `Int` as well.

Comment: Is there any reason the return type of `length` isn't polymorphic?

Comment: @mnoronha Yes, for example perfomence. But you can use `genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i`

Comment: @mnoronha See also: [*Why isn't \`length\` generic by default?*](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/211053/101698) at SE.SE.

Answer (score 8):

Here goes a step-by-step take on this question.

Let's begin with:

```
((lenDigits . factorial) 199) <= 199
```

According to the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1)...

> An integer literal represents the application of the function `fromInteger` to the appropriate value of type `Integer`.

That means our first expression is actually:

```
((lenDigits . factorial) (fromInteger (199 :: Integer)) 
    <= (fromInteger (199 :: Integer))
```

By itself, `fromInteger (199 :: Integer)` has the polymorphic type `Num a => a`. We now have to see whether this type is specialised in the context of the whole expression. Note that, until we find a reason for it not being so, we should assume that the polymorphic types of the two occurrences of `fromInteger (199 :: Integer)` are independent (`Num a => a` and `Num b => b`, if you will).

`lenDigits` is `Show a => a -> Int`, and so the...

```
(lenDigits . factorial) (fromInteger (199 :: Integer))
```

... to the left of the `<=` must be an `Int`. Given that `(<=)` is `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`, the `fromInteger (199 :: Integer)` to the right of the `<=` also has to be an `Int`. The whole expression then becomes:

```
((lenDigits . factorial) (fromInteger (199 :: Integer)) <= (199 :: Int)
```

While the second `199` was specialised to `Int`, the first one is still polymorphic. In the absence of other type annotations, defaulting makes it specialise to `Integer` when we use the expression in GHCi. Therefore, we ultimately get:

```
((lenDigits . factorial) (199 :: Integer)) <= (199 :: Int)
```

Now, on to the second expression:

```
(\i -> ((lenDigits . factorial) i) <= i) 199
```

By the same reasoning used above, `(lenDigits . factorial) i` (to the left of `<=`) is an `Int`, and so `i` (to the right of `<=`) is also an `Int`. That being so, we have...

```
GHCi> :t \i -> (lenDigits . factorial) i <= i
\i -> (lenDigits . factorial) i <= i :: Int -> Bool
```

... and therefore applying it to `199` (which is actually `fromInteger (199 :: Integer)`) specialises it to int, giving:

```
((lenDigits . factorial) (199 :: Int)) <= (199 :: Int)
```

The first `199` is now `Int` rather than `Integer`. `factorial (199 :: Int)` overflows the fixed size `Int` type, leading to a bogus result. One way of avoiding that would be introducing an explicit `fromInteger` in order to get something equivalent to the first scenario:

```
GHCi> :t \i -> (lenDigits . factorial) i <= fromInteger i
\i -> (lenDigits . factorial) i <= fromInteger i :: Integer -> Bool
GHCi> (\i -> (lenDigits . factorial) i <= fromInteger i) 199
False
```